# Lg .dz .kdz file structure

Tags: java, mobile, decompiling, lg

Im asking for a bit much here but maybe some can point me or help me understand how .kdz and .dz file work, meaning I want to understated their structure and possible build a java script to compress (as a self project), also how can I read or utilize the dll file in the kdz.

I have a python script that can decompress those file, can any one help me understand it?

Comment: given they end in 'z', it's likely they're gzipped, or perhaps bz2'd

Comment: couldn't decompress with any bz2 tools(for win)

Comment: I have a python script that can decompress those file, can any one help me understand it?